# When is it safe to close CAsyncSocket?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, mfc, casyncsocket

`CAsyncSocket` crashes my application if I delete the `CAsyncSocket` after a call to `Connect`, but before the `OnConnect` callback has been called.  `ASSERT(pSocket != NULL)` fails in `CAsyncSocket::DoCallBack` and the application exits.

In other words, if I create a `CAsyncSocket`, try to connect it to a server, and then kill it before that connection either succeeds or fails, I have problems. I can avoid this particular crash by implementing `OnConnect` and setting a flag which indicates that the connection attempt completed. If the flag is false I know it's not safe to delete.

Are there other cases I need to check for before I delete the object? Is there a single way to  check if it's safe? Or do I need to implement all of the callbacks for any operation I might initiate (`OnReceive`, `OnSend`, `OnConnect` ) and ensure those callbacks have been called?

Comment: Can't you close it before deleting it?

Comment: Sure, but the destructor calls Close, so I'm not sure how that would be any better than simply deleting it.

Comment: You're right. I couldn't even find any way to cancel outstanding operations. But there must be a way to cleanly do that.

Comment: Are the methods of the instance of the `CAsyncSocket` class called from different threads?

Comment: Related question: [CAsyncSocket::Close Crashes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1265308).

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [FIX: Assertion Failed, Line 475 of Sockcore.cpp, Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/139692) article to perform the analysis.

### Additional references:

1. [How to Handle CAsyncSocket::OnClose Gracefully, Alan Ning](https://askldjd.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/how-to-handle-casyncsocketonclose-gracefully/).
2. [Write a Simple HTTP-based Server Using MFC and Windows Sockets, David Cook, 
   February 1996, Microsoft Systems Journal](https://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/S25F.aspx): MFC "dead" sockets map.